# My question seemes to be frozen

Tags: support

I had a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158083/mistakenly-modified-bin-sh) that was doing very well & the number of views as well as likes was increasing fast, but I don't know why suddenly everything stopped & now it behaves as if it's a duplicate or closed post.Is there any reason? Such a sudden change seems really abnormal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually your question is now at normal state. You were getting so much interaction before because your question became a hot network question and was also tweeted by the automated Ask Ubuntu twitter account. See [the timeline of your question:](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1158083/timeline)

> [image]

Enough time has passed that both of these are probably irrelevant now, hence the drop off in views.